# PHP 5.3.10 SOAP server fails to process large messages

Tags: php, soap

We have a SOAP service that receives files as byte content. This service works fine for small files, but is failing for files ~25MB or larger. In the case of large files, the SOAP call executes but returns null. It literally returns nothing--no error message, no message at all. My associate indicated that the server is generating a 500 internal server error, which somehow gets back to the client but disappears in my testing. Tracing the code indicates that the handle() method of the code is not throwing an eror but also not doing anything at all--not calling the service's authorization method nor the method that puts the file to the server.

What is the likely cause of this problem, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the client that calls the soap stop the service before having the answer.

Try to increase the value of `default_socket_timeout` in your php.ini.
You can also increase the value of `max_execution_time`

I hope it will help you. :)